# Consecutive non square free numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was thinking to solve this by computer programs but I prefer a solution.

How to obtain a list of 3 consecutive non square free positive integers? In general, how to obtain the same kind of list with $k$ elements? Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Let $n$ be the first number.  It will work if we can arrange for the following:
$$
n\equiv 0\pmod{4}
$$
$$
n+1\equiv 0\pmod{9}
$$
$$
n+2\equiv 0\pmod{25}
$$
Using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_Remainder_Theorem), the first two congruences are equivalent to requiring that $n\equiv 8 \pmod{36}$.  Combining this with the third congruence gives that $n\equiv 548\pmod{900}$.  Thus, three such numbers are $548$, $549$, and $550$.

A similar algorithm works for $k$ consecutive square-free numbers.

Comment: By subtracting from $900$ you instantly get $350$, $351$ and $352$ as another triplet, and not surprisingly there are six triplets involving multiples of $2^2$, $3^2$ and $4^2$ in every $900$ integers corresponding to the permutations of the three squares.

Comment: Hi. Why are you supposing the first number $n$ being $n\equiv 0 (\mod 4)$?

Comment: @Thiago This is the same as saying that $n$ is a multiple of $4$, which will guarantee that it isn't square-free.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But if $n$ is not multiple of 4 it could be still non-free square. To find 3 numbers, OK, you got it. But may I think like you in the general case? For example, to find a list with 30 consecutive numbers. May we suppose $n\equiv 0 \mod 4$?. 

Does your solution states that we always find such a list starting with a multiple of 4? Even for $k$ numbers instead of 3? Thanks.

Comment: @Thiago  For $4$ numbers, you would want the same three conditions, plus $n+3\equiv 0\pmod{49}$.  For $5$ numbers, you would also add in $n+4 \equiv 0\pmod{121}$.  And so forth.

Comment: It's interesting how your solution is composed by large numbers. See the other solution below, given by Patrick. It starts with multiple of 4 but uses power of 5 and 7, not 3 as yours. I guess that it's impossible to know which primes to use to obtain a small solution.

Answer (score 5):

$48 = 3 \times 2^4,49 = 7^2,50 = 2 \times 5^2$ would be the first example of a sequence with $3$ consecutive numbers. I found it simply by looking at them all until I found the first one. Given any set of distinct coprime numbers $a_1, \dots, a_k$, the Chinese Remainder Theorem ensures us of the existence of a solution to $n + i \equiv 0 \pmod {a_i}$, which gives you at least the existence of some large possibility for a sequence of non-square free consecutive integers.

For the info, the first consecutive non-square free integers I found were $(8,9)$, $(24,25)$ and $(44,45)$. Then I found $(48,49,50)$. Note that you can easily generate infinitely many such triples in the following manner : Since the prime divisors of $(48,49,50)$ that are the square parts of them are $2,5,7$, then the triple ($48 + k(2\times 5 \times 7)^2$, $49 + k(2 \times 5 \times 7)^2$, $50 + k (2 \times 5 \times 7)^2$) is also a sequence of three consecutive non-square free numbers ($k \in \mathbb N$).

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks for the first list. I can not believe that I didn't find it... lol

Comment: Thiago : Sometimes we must not think that computers do everything, it is possible to just quickly try our own hands at it. Computers are mostly useful when you expect things to get large. There are not many consecutive non-squarefree at first because there are lots of small primes and products of small primes, but as you make the size grow just a little, non-squarefree numbers own the place.

Comment: Yes. I am trying to find larger lists. Maybe you want to edit your post to correct the index $a_i$ and the parenthesis on the second number of your general list. I tried but it does not work.

Comment: @Thiago : I just forgot to put some $\{$ $\}$, but thanks for noticing.

Comment: How about $49+k(2\times 5\times 7)$, ...

Comment: Thiago : You want to make sure that adding the multiple keeps the non-squarefreeness of the numbers, that is precisely why I add a multiple of the square of the primes. If you would try the triple $48,49,50$ + $2\times 5 \times 7$, note how $48 + 70$ is not divisible by $4$ anymore.

Comment: Sorry. I was talking about the miss print. You forgot to close the ). Thanks.

Comment: @Thiago, oh, lol, my bad. I'll fix this too!

Answer (score 0):

See http://oeis.org/A045882 and references given there.

Comment: Thanks so much. The list is very interesting.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to obtain infinitely many sets of $3$ consecutive non-square-free positive integers.

Note that there are infinitely many solutions to the [negative Pell equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531833/generating-all-solutions-for-a-negative-pell-equation) $ n^2−2m^2=−1.$

Given a solution $(n,m)$, $n$ must be odd, so $\color{blue}{n^2-1}$ is divisible by $4=2^2$;

$\color{blue}{n^2}$ is a square; and $\color{blue}{n^2+1=2m^2}$ is twice a square.