# Are there infinitely many sets of triples $\{ x,x+1,x+2\}$ that are square free?

Tags: number-theory

I suppose there are a series of such questions, depending on the length of the set, staring with pairs, and the power that is supposed to be missing from the divisors.

[Here is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160547/consecutive-non-square-free-numbers)  a problem insisting on the opposite; that the numbers should all have a certain power as divisor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same question has been asked and answered on MathOverflow:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59741/are-there-infinitely-many-triples-of-consecutive-square-free-integers

Comment: Thanks, oddly enough my few searches did not locate that page. Is there an elementary answer for pairs of consecutive numbers?