# Constant Hiding Behind Particular Pythagorean Triples

Tags: limits, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, integers, pythagorean-triples

The question pertains to an apparent constant appearing behind Pythagorean Triples whose "legs" have a difference of 1.

To start, here are the first 5 triples that satisfy the above condition:

(20, 21, 29)

(119, 120, 169)

(696, 697, 985)

(4059, 4060, 5741)

(23660, 23661, 33461)

If you take the average of the first two legs, call it $a_n$, and divide $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, you get the following decimals:

$\frac{a_1}{a_0}=\frac{119.5}{20.5}=5.82926829268$

$\frac{a_2}{a_1}=\frac{696.5}{119.5}=5.82926829268$

$\frac{a_3}{a_2}=\frac{4059.5}{696.5}=5.82842785355$

$\frac{a_4}{a_3}=\frac{23660.5}{4059.5}=5.8284271462$

To me, it clearly appears to be approaching some constant and I would like some help working out how to solve for the closed form of this constant. I also doubt this is a new observation but I had trouble finding literature on it so if someone could provide a link, I would appreciate it!

Comment: That's $3+2\sqrt 2$.  See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893253/are-there-finitely-many-pythagorean-triples-whose-smallest-two-numbers-differ-by).

Comment: your sequence of numbers obeys $a_{n+2} = 6 a_{n+1}  - a_n$

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for and now my question is answered! Thank you :)

Comment: Why don't you count (3,4,5) as the first triple?

Comment: The ratio approaches
\begin{align*} 
\cot^2(\dfrac{π}{8})\approx 5.8284271247461900976\\
\\
3 + 2 \sqrt{2} \approx 5.8284271247461900976\\
\\
(1 + \sqrt{2})^2 \approx 5.8284271247461900976
\end{align*}