# Recurrence relation solution to negative Pell's equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, pell-type-equations

I'm trying to determine how to get the sequence of possible solutions for a negative Pell's equation:
$$
x^2 - 2y^2=-1
$$
I know that the fundamental solution is $x_1=1$ and $y_1=1$, but I don't know how to get the recurrence relation to get all the solutions.

I have seen found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531833/generating-all-solutions-for-a-negative-pell-equation) that the recurrence relation is:
$$
x_{n+1}=3x_n+4y_n,\qquad y_{n+1}=2x_n+3y_n.
$$
Which is similar to the recurrence relation for positive Pell's equations found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#Solutions):

$$
x_{k+1} = x_1x_k+ny_1y_k,\qquad
y_{k+1} = x_1y_k+y_1x_k 
$$
Using $x_1=3$ and $y_1=2$, but I don't  understand why do we use those values instead of those of the fundamental solution.

How are the recurrence relations for negative Pell's equations obtained? (particularly for this case)

Comment: Given $(1+\sqrt2)(1-\sqrt2)=-1$, $(1+\sqrt2)^2(1-\sqrt2)^2=(3+2\sqrt2)(3-2\sqrt2)=+1$, so if $(x+\sqrt2y)(x-\sqrt2y)=-1$ then $(x+\sqrt2y)(1+\sqrt2)(x-\sqrt2y)(1-\sqrt2)=1$, but $(x+\sqrt2y)(3+2\sqrt2)(x-\sqrt2y)(3-2\sqrt2)=-1$

Comment: Thank you very much. If I understand correctly, we can conclude from your last equation that we can get more solutions by multiplying the original equation ($x^2 - 2y^2=-1$) by $(3+2\sqrt2)(3-2\sqrt2)$ and then rearranging the terms to get new solutions ($x_{k+1}, y_{k+1}$) in terms of the initial solutions ($x_k,y_k$)?

Comment: You're welcome; I think you understand correctly

Comment: Thank you very much. You have been a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the comment from @J.W.Tanner, $$x_{n+1}+\sqrt2y_{n+1}=(x_n+\sqrt2y_n)(3+2\sqrt2)=(3x_n+4y_n)+(2x_n+3y_n)\sqrt2$$ is one way to get $x_{n+1}=3x_n+4y_n$, $y_{n+1}=2x_n+3y_n$.

Comment: Gerry, I think it was Asaf and I who experimented with pings inside answers. The conclusion, which may be exactly what you intended, was that this visually helps call attention to that username, but does not product a ping (for Tanner, a little red sign of new notifications in the upper right) this way.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3&4 \\
 2&3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The matrix was traditionally called an "automorph."

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3&2 \\
 4&3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0\\
 0 & -2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3&4 \\
 2&3 \\
\end{array}
\right)=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & -2\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

That is why....

Cayley-Hamilton is what tells us that

$$ x_{n+2} = 6 x_{n+1} - x_n $$
$$ y_{n+2} = 6 y_{n+1} - y_n $$

The $x$ values begin
$$ 1, 7,  41, 239, 1393,  8119, 47321, 275807, 1607521,... $$
The $y$ values begin
$$ 1, 5,  29, 169, 985,  5741, 33461, 195025, 1136689,... $$

This can also be proved by ordinary calculations.