# Find big perfect squares in the form 2x^2 - 1

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to find integer solutions for $x$ $$x = \sqrt{2a^2 - 1}$$
Where $a$ is an *odd* integer bigger than $\mathrm{1\times10^{12}}$.

I have no idea where to start with this. Is there any general solution, except running through possible values of $a$ bigger than $\mathrm{1\times10^{12}}$?

Comment: Are you familiar with Pell's equation? You want integer solutions to $x^2 - 2a^2 = - 1$.

Comment: You should write "1e12" here as $10^{12}$.  In any case, why is it important that $a > 10^{12}$? Study this problem with *small* $a$ to see patterns.   Requiring $a > 10^{12}$ seems like an artificial restriction.  It is also unnecessary to say in advance that you want $a$ to be odd, since when $x^2 - 2a^2 = -1$, we can prove $a$ *must* be odd if it exists at all: if $a$ is even and $x^2 - 2a^2 = -1$ then $x^2 \equiv -1 \equiv 7 \bmod 8$ and that has no solution.

Comment: Cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#The_negative_Pell's_equation)

Comment: Also cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531833/generating-all-solutions-for-a-negative-pell-equation)

Comment: @CalvinLin Pell's equation was the best solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First thing which comes in my mind, is this:

$$x^2 = 2a^2-1 \iff x^2-a^2=a^2-1 \iff (x-a) \cdot (x+a) = (a+1) \cdot (a-1)$$

Now it's a game of finding numbers, who can be written as $pq=rs$, who obey the mentioned equation.

Comment: $7^2=2\cdot5^2-1$ is a solution besides $x=\pm1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: Nice one: $(7-5) \cdot (7+5) = (5-1) \cdot (5+1)$. (I'll update my answer)