# For any positive integers $m$ and $n$, there are $n$ consecutive positive integers divisible by $a^m$ for some integer $a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

The problem is

> Prove that for any positive integers $m$ and $n$, there exist a set of $n$ consecutive positive integers each of which is divisible by a number of the form $a^m$, where $a$ is some integer in $\Bbb{N}$.

When I first saw this question, it seemed quite trivial to start with $a=1$. I don't think that there can be any other possibility of $a$. Kindly help me if I'm going wrong.

Any hint would be appreciated. If possible, a hint/solution involving basic theorems of integers (preferably not modular arithmetic) would be highly helpful.

Comment: Presumably the problem meant to exclude $a=1$. Hint: consider divisibility by $p_1^m, \dots,p_n^m$ where the $p_j$ are distinct primes. And I suggest embracing modular arithmetic—trying to avoid it is just putting obstacles in your own way.

Comment: @GregMartin Why did you consider exactly n distinct primes?

Comment: @GregMartin I completely agree that modular arithmetic might be the way to go. But this problem was included as a part of arithmetic of integers chapter of the textbook 'Challenge and Thrill of Pre-College Mathematics', so I felt going with the essence of the chapter, where modular arithmetic isn't introduced :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this problem appear in exercise lists when introducing Chinese Remainder Theorem (in my case for math olympiads).

The solution is usually to take a positive integer $k$ that is congruent to $-i \bmod p_i^m$ where $p_i$ is the $i$'th prime. If we do this we can note in the consecutive integers $k+1,\dots,k+n$ the $i$'th integer is divisible by $p_i^m$.

---

Update: I think this result is very closely related to chinese remainder theorem. Note that for large vlaues of $n$ you are going to require arbitrarily many different primes to divide the different terms, I don't believe there is going to be a nice shortcut that allows you to ignore CRT like arguments.

Comment: Is there any other way than CRT to approach this problem?

Comment: Sorry I don't know.

Comment: This question is related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160547/consecutive-non-square-free-numbers#:~:text=For%20the%20info%2C%20the%20first,and%20(44%2C45), also this one: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151210/runs-of-consecutive-non-squarefree-integers

Comment: @AarushMishra I have been thinking about the problem and expanded my solution, what do you think?

Comment: Yep, now I have started reading the basics of modular arithmetic. I am still on the basic properties though. Would surely give a try to this problem again after understanding CRT. Thanks for your help

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 0):

We need to show that $\exists a_i$ s.t. $a_i^m | x_i$ where $x_1, x_2 \ldots, x_n$ are $n$ consecutive natural numbers and $a_i \neq 1$, for $1\le i\le n$. Thus, $a_i$ is divisible by at least one prime, let $p_i$ be the smallest prime dividing $a_i$. Notice that $p_i^m|x_i$. So, we will concern ourselves with $x_i$ divisible by $m$th power of a prime.

Define:
$$p = \prod_{i = 1}^n p_i^m$$
Given any integer $m$, we prove the claim by inducting on $n$. (The proof does not specifically use $m$, hence there is no need to induct on it.)

For $n = 1$, the problem is trivial: take $x_1 = 2^m$. Suppose the claim is true for $n = k$, i.e. $\exists$ prime $p_1,\ldots p_k$ s.t. $p_i^m | x_i$ for $1\le i\le k$, where $x_1< \ldots< x_k$ are consecutive positive integers. 
Let $y_i = x_i + zp$, and $y_{k+1} = y_k + 1$. We will find an algorithm for finding a non-negative integer $z$ s.t. $y_{k+1}$ is a multiple of $m$th power of a prime. 
Let $q$ be the smallest prime larger than $x_k$. Singe $\gcd(p,q^m) = 1$, by [Bezout's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) we conclude that $\exists u,v \in \Bbb Z$ s.t :
$$up + vq^m = 1$$WLOG assume $u\le 0$, then we have
$$u(-1-x_i)p \equiv -1 - x_i \pmod{q^m}$$Setting $z = u(-1-x_i)\ge 0$ we observe that:
$$\begin{aligned}y_{n+1} &= x_n + u(-1-a_i)p + 1\\ &\equiv x_n -x_n - 1+1 \pmod{q^m}\\ &\equiv 0 \pmod{q^m}\end{aligned}$$
Thus, $q^m|y_{n+1}$ which completes our proof.

Comment: Although CRT is most suitable for this question, the OP had asked for an answer without it. Also, we can avoid the mod by some elementary application of division lemma

Comment: This answer is essentially the same as Asinomás's answer, except instead of invoking CRT by name, you have repeated inline a proof of  [Easy CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242) to solve $\, x\equiv 0\pmod{p},\, x\equiv -1-a_i\pmod{q^m}.\,$ But this is no simpler than the general proof of CRT, so it is better to simply invoke CRT and let the reader learn the general proof - whose idea is obfuscated when inlined in the above special case; i.e. don't work against *abstraction* when it is no more difficult than the special case at hand.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).