# Number theory on multiples of squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

If we take the numbers $ 48 $, $ 49 $ and $ 50 $, we can see that they are all consecutive integers and multiples of squares ($48$ is multiple of $2^2$, $49$ is multiple of $7^2$ and $50$ is multiple of $5^2$).

Is it possible to prove that there are infinitely many triples of consecutive integers which satisfy this condition, and is there a quadruple of consecutive integers which satisfy it?
I would define $n$, $n+1$ and $n+2$, and by trying to square them I got $n^2$, $n^2+2n+1$ and $n^2+4n+2$. What can I do to prove the statement?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149194/consecutive-non-squarefree-integers/149198#149198

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Consecutive non square free numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160547/consecutive-non-square-free-numbers)  And for a more general statement, see [For any positive integers $m$ and $n$, there are $n$ consecutive positive integers divisible by $a^m$ for some integer $a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4451170).

Comment: If $n$ is a solution to the negative Pell equation $n^2-2m^2=-1$, then $n^2+1$ is twice a square, $n^2$ is a square, and $n^2-1$ is a multiple of $2^2=4$

Answer (score 1):

If you add $2^2\cdot 7^2\cdot 5^2=4900$ to your solution, you get another $4948,4949,4950$ that satisfy the same property (with the same squares in fact). You can do this as many times as you like, so there are infinitely many solutions.

Say we want $x$ such that

\begin{align*}
x&\equiv 0 \bmod 2^2\\
x+1&\equiv 0 \bmod 7^2\\
x+2 &\equiv 0\bmod 5^2
\end{align*}

then the Chinese remainder theorem gives us infinitely many solutions. The same is true if we choose four square moduli and four consecutive integers etc.

Comment: Just to add to this, note that $9$ doesn't divide $4900$; so you'll easily be able to extend to four consecutive integers (and so on). Of course, some of these solutions with four will trivially extend to a solution with five consecutive integers; but you can extend this as much as you want.

Comment: Better link to [a duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160547) than edit another answer, Joshua. As for an even more general statement, @ChrisLewis, see [For any positive integers $m$ and $n$, there are $n$ consecutive positive integers divisible by $a^m$ for some integer $a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4451170).